# How can I comment in the file denoted by javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source

Tags: sql, jpa, comments, persistence.xml

I'm using `javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source` for my unit testing.
Is there any standard way to put comments on the script?

The file contains insert statements for my entities.

```sql
INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (...) -- 1
INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (...) -- 2
```

I want to comment the generated id value for myself.

P.S. I'm using H2, Derby, and HSQLDB as in-memory databases and EclipseLink and Hibernate as JPA implementations.

Comment: How do you comment in any SQL ? that is what you do. If your JPA provider doesn't allow that then raise an issue on them

Comment: @BillyFrost I'm not an expert but isn't `--` universal?

Comment: works on all RDBMS I've used

Answer (score 0):

The implementation in EclipseLink ignores lines which are starting with an `#`. Comments at the end of line aren't currently supported, though.

You can have a look at it on [Github](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/blob/17a37026e4b2e3cccc07e2beda7d926552025956/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/EntityManagerSetupImpl.java#L4592):

```java
// Remove trailing and leading white space characters.
String sqlString = sqlBuffer.toString().trim();

// If the string isn't empty, then fire it.
if ((! sqlString.equals("")) && (! sqlString.startsWith("#"))) {
```